# Operator precedence and order of evaluation in the implementation of std::transform

Tags: c++, c++17, std, operator-precedence, order-of-execution

**SUMMARY**

I stumbled upon the implementation of `std::transform` and I could not figure out why it works in the case where we transform a container in-place. In particular, I found this expression confusing `*d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);`.

**CODE**

Using the first implementation of `std::transform` found here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform, I wrote this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class InputIt,
          class OutputIt,
          class UnaryOperation >
OutputIt transform( InputIt first1,
                    InputIt last1,
                    OutputIt d_first, 
                    UnaryOperation unary_op )
{
  while (first1 != last1) {
    *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);
  }
  return d_first;
}

int main() {
  int arr[5] {1,2,3,4,5};  

  transform(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),
        std::begin(arr),
        [](auto i){return i*i;});
  
  for (auto& elem : arr) std::cout << elem << std::endl;  

  return 0;
}
```

**ATTEMPT FOR AN EXPLANATION**

After doing some reading in the C++ standard, Cpp reference, and SO, I think I might be able to explain what happens in that confusing (for me) statement. Let's decompose this expression:

```
*d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++); // same as A = B;
```

1. First resolve what is happening on `B`, which is, `unary_op(*first1++)`
2. Now resolve the parentheses `*first1++` which means `*(first1++)` which means a) make a copy of the
   dereferenced `first1` and b) pass it to the function, then c) increment the iterator.
3. The copied dereferenced `first1` is multiplied by itself inside the `unary_op`.
4. Now `B` is evaluated, time to deal with the assignment.
5. Assign `B` to the dereferenced value of `d_first`.
6. When this assignment is complete, and before we go to the next statement (whatever that may be)
   increment the `d_first` iterator.

This way, the two iterators are "on the same page", meaning at the same position of the arrays which they iterate.

**QUESTIONS**

My questions are:

A) Is the above explanation correct?

B) Which operations in that expression are *evaluations* and which *computations*?

C) Since `*first1++` translates to `*(first1++)` but the dereferencing happens before the incrementation, isn't that confusing to remember? However, `(*first1)++` would mean something totally different, i.e. dereference `first1` and pass it to the function and then increment this value by one; not the iterator! Any hints to remember how to untangle myself in such expressions?

Comment: "_but the dereferencing happens before the incrementation_" - no, it doesn't. The increment is done first, but a _copy_ of the old value is "returned" by the postfix `++`. It's that copy that gets dereferenced.

Comment: *"but the dereferencing happens before the incrementation"*. It is not pedantically true. deferencing happens after the increment, but on the value returned by `first1++` which is the one before the incrementation.

Comment: *"make a copy of the dereferenced first1"* The copy is made only because the function receives the parameter by value.

Comment: I think OP meant "happens before the incrementation" in a 'it comes first when reading left-to-right' sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just answering C).

> Any hints to remember how to untangle myself in such expressions?

`*i++`, `*dst++ = do_something_with(*src++);`, etc., are well-established patterns in C++ and C. Therefore, the suggestion is:

- If you mean `*(first++)`, write it as `*first++`, because it is the least surprising. (And get used to reading this expression the right way.)
- If you mean `(*first)++`, then write it as such. (You have no choice anyway.) The presence of the parentheses indicates immediately, that a meaning is intended that is different from `*first++`.